# How to troubleshoot angular app hosted in WSL2

Tags: wsl-2

*I am very new to development, so I apologize in advance if I am not being clear enough. I appreciate any feedback on the question and how to better pose it.*

I'm currently working on an angular app hosted in WSL2. To get it to run locally, this is what I do:

1. Launch solution in VS Code
2. From terminal, run `npm start`
3. Then, I click on Run and Debug
4. Once I get the `Now listening on: .....` message, I move on to Chrome to start debugging my app

Since this morning, I keep getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the browser, and **I'm currently waiting on IT to step in as there could have been some security changes placed that are blocking the requests**. Also, I'm not using the VPN.

In the meantime, is there a way to know for sure (or get as close as possible to) what is causing the connection to be refused in my particular scenario? I'm curious about it, but I don't know how to even search the topic properly due to lack of proper terms.

What should one do to at least obtain more details about the issue on their own (perhaps, to help expedite help by collecting important info upfront)? Where my apps are hosted in WSL2, I get very confused between the ip address originating the request and that of the server.

I appreciate any guidance anyone could provide.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there was a VPN software running where the firewall was ON, even though I was not in the VPN (it went on after I connected to the VPN the previous day). I guess there was nothing else I could have done anyway.